# odoo14 'thread.getMemberName is not a function' after update

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-14

I just updated to the latest odoo image using docker (Odoo 14.0-20211229 (Community Edition)). Everything works, except if I open the discuss module, I get this Odoo-client error:

```
Error: scope['threadView'].thread.getMemberName is not a function. (In 'scope['threadView'].thread.getMemberName(scope['message'].author)', 'scope['threadView'].thread.getMemberName' is undefined)
anonymous@
render@[native code]
__render@https://rectanglemaps.com/web/content/5292-6384825/web.assets_common.js:1298:41
@https://rectanglemaps.com/web/content/5292-6384825/web.assets_common.js:1296:37
asyncFunctionResume@[native code]
@[native code]
promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise@[native code]
```

I have no idea where it comes from, all other modules work fine.

Answer (score 1):

here it has open request is submitted on the official **Odoo repository** [82424](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/82424) you can keep track until it is resolved.